# Failing to open a PDF in gview

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to open a document with

I cant get the documents to preview. Not sure what Im missing here.
Been through quite a few StackOverflow question/answers regarding this already, but still no success.

**url =** `http://192.168.0.6:8077/files/StaffReport.pdf`

```
                 <iframe
                    className={'pdf'}
                    width="100%"
                    height="600"
                    frameBorder="0"
                    src={`https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${this.props.file}&embedded=true`}
                 />
```

But I keep on getting **No preview available**

Answer (score 1):

Likely, google cannot access your url because it's a local ip mapped to your local network
(unless it just fetches from the locally running code and shows you that, but I don't know if that's how it works),

I would recommend trying to upload that file somewhere accessible to the internet, and then trying again.

Comment: What about a mapped folder? Thing is, I am storing files on the server and need to preview them on the client side. I have tried a mapped folder but its not working, not sure if im using it incorrect. `\\LOCAL-PC\mapped folder\TEMP.docx`

Comment: I think, the way you will know if it will work or not is this:  If a stranger on the internet can't access the file. I think that google can't either. I don't think that Gview  can view local only files, be that on a local network or on your machine with localhost.
https://imgur.com/fBrWvaK
In this image you can see there are no requests for a PDF that is embedded, google sends you it's own data interpreted. Which means it needs to be accessible to the internet.


https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-hamilton-dgy1w


Working example.